Thevenin's Theorem with parallel voltage source
I have the following circuit

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
I am asked to find the Thevenin equivalent voltage on the branch containing L.
To me, it looks like I can disregard the right most resistor because all the current will flow through the branch containing the E2 voltage source. This way, the circuit has only the top two resistors.

simulate this circuit
The voltage on terminal A (V_A) can be expressed then as R*I and voltage on terminal B (V_B) as 2R*I where I equals (E2-E1)/(R+R). The equivalent voltage then should be V_B - V_A. Am I getting this wrong?

Hi,
Welcome. You need to add references to all pictures where you found them or if you made them yourself.

@Tyassin Those are Circuit Labs schematics from the schematic editor built into the question editor. You can tell because they have a ‘simulate this circuit’ link below them.

Normally you'd choose node B as the reference (aka "ground") node and define its voltage to be 0. Then (if you can't see the answer by inspection) you'd use mesh or node analysis to find the voltage at A relative to the reference.

Thanks. I'll try doing that. Can you please also confirm that I was allowed to cut out the right most resistor from the first diagram?

@v0id Is that a DC circuit, AC circuit, or some transient analysis circuit? For all we know, at DC the inductor could be a short circuit.
